# Unzip zip file on Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to unzip my zip file on google colab but it is not working for me below are the details

**Command used**

```
!unzip "drive/MyDrive/Dog Vision2/dog-breed-identification.zip" -d "drive/MyDrive/Dog Vision2"
```

**Error Message**

```
Archive:  drive/MyDrive/Dog Vision2/dog-breed-identification.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of drive/MyDrive/Dog Vision2/dog-breed-identification.zip or
        drive/MyDrive/Dog Vision2/dog-breed-identification.zip.zip, and cannot find drive/MyDrive/Dog Vision2/dog-breed-identification.zip.ZIP, period.
```

**File Name Snippet**

[image]

**Note: I am able to unzip same file on my local machine.**

Comment: Shouldn't the path be absolute, like `/drive/MyDrive/Dog Vision2/dog-breed-identification.zip`?

Comment: You can install "Zip Extractor for Google Drive" from the Google Workspace Marketplace. It will enable you to extract the zip file without the need to involve Colab. https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/search/ZIP%20Extractor

Comment: Thank you ForceBru and Dan Nagle for quick replies. I found that my zip was not uploaded successfully so it was failing.  Same mistake should not happen with other so I have posted the checks below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad, I just saw my zip file was not fully uploaded.

For others, please re-check if the file is uploaded on drive or not, before running unzip command. PFB snippet where you can check it.

[image]

Note :

- At Bottom of the left panel we can see if the file is uploaded
  successfully or not.
- Red Highlighted is the zip which was not uploaded successfully.
- Green Highlighted is the zip which is in progress.